# Is it possible to create a foreign key relationship between two tables on String/varchar type columns in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have a categories table which has an id and a slug(varchar type) column.I want to create a subcategories table which will have a column category_slug(varchar type) that will reference the slug column in the Category table.

I am getting errors during php artisan migrate.

```
    Schema::create('subcategories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('category_slug')->unique();
        $table->integer('product_id');
        $table->foreign('category_slug')
       ->references('slug')->on('categories');
        $table->timestamps();
  });
```

The errors in the terminal are.

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1005 Can't create table `laravel_eshopper`.  `#sql-ee8_272` (errno:
>   150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")  (SQL: alter table
>   `tabpanes` add constraint `tabpanes_category_slug_foreign` foreign
>   key (`category_slug`) references `categories` (`slug`))
>
> [PDOException]  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create
>   table `laravel_eshopper`.  `#sql-ee8_272` (errno: 150 "Foreign key
>   constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: Why such type of database design?

Comment: There is another column 'product_id' in the subcategories table.I have edited the post.which stores id's of products from product table.I want that anyone see the subcategories table can understand easily which product belong to which category.A foreign key relation will help me to insert data in the subcategories table easily because all the slugs will come as dropdown at the time of insertion in the subcategories table from phpmyadmin.

Comment: why do you need to create another table for `subcategories`, you can create `parent_id` in the `category`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes Surely You can do that See the Example Below:

Suppose you have your category table as below:

```
  Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
  });
```

Now You can create subcategories with foreign key as below:

```
 Schema::create('subcategories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('category_slug')->unique();
        $table->foreign('category_slug')
       ->references('slug')->on('categories')->onUpdate('cascade')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
  });
```

Comment: Thanks!! my slug column in the categories table was not defined unique.